# Conditional show alert component with the option to remove component from view

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a form in React. Within this form I have an alert component, showing a response message if submission went OK or bad.

My form looks like this:

```
<form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
    {
        this.state.error &&
        <Alert text={this.state.error} />
    }
    <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Enter link url"
        value={this.state.url}
        onChange={this.onUrlChange} />

    <button type="submit">Add link</button>
</form>
```

My state has an error property, if this is set, it will show the alert component. Within my alert component I want to show the giving text set by my form:

```
const Alert = ({ text, closeCallback }) => (
    <div className="alert">
        {text}
        <button onClick={(e) => closeCallback()}>X</button>
    </div>
);
```

From within my alert component I want to be able to remove the component from the view and make it disappear from the parent render. But how?

I know I can send a callback function from parent (which set the error state to empty string) down to my alert component like:

```
<Alert closeCallback={parentFunction()} text={this.state.error} />
```

But for every time I want to use my alert component in this scenario, I have to create that exact callback function in my parent component together with my condition `this.state.error && <Alert text={this.state.error} />`. Can I somehow avoid this?

I'm new to React btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep the function inside and just return `null` in render, it tells React to render nothing, like this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

class Alert extends Component {
  state = {
    isVisible: true
  };
  handleToggleState = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      isVisible: !prevState.isVisible
    }));
  };
  render() {
    return this.state.isVisible ? (
      <div className="alert">
        {this.props.text}
        <button onClick={this.handleToggleState}>X</button>
      </div>
    ) : null;
  }
}

class Form extends Component {
  state = { error: "Some weird error" };
  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
        {this.state.error && <Alert text={this.state.error} />}
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter link url"
          value={this.state.url}
          onChange={this.onUrlChange}
        />

        <button type="submit">Add link</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

render(<Form />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Aha, yes I like it. I will just have to remember to set my error state to empty when submitting the form for the component to reenter the view..

Comment: Well the question formulated in description was not about that, it's a separate issue. You specifically asked how to remove a component without exposing the callback, I think from that standpoint the question is answered.

Comment: Ah yes ofcouse Karen I do not disagree. It was merely a comment of thought. But I’m also asking to not have the this.state.error condition in my parent component. Well I came up with something in that regard in my answer below. And that answers my question completly. I will accept your answer as it pointed me in the direction - thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just fiddled around with @Karens answer and came up with the following, depending on componentWillReceiveProps so I dont have to have the condition in my form view, keeping it all internal for my Alert component:

```
class Alert extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      text: props.text
    };
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(e) {
    this.setState(e);
  }

  onHide = () => {
    this.setState({ text: '' });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      this.state.text ? (
        <div style={{backgroundColor: 'Red'}}>
          {this.state.text}
          <button onClick={this.onHide}>X</button>
        </div>
      ) : null
    )
  }
}

class Form extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      error: ''
    };
  }

  onRender = () => {
    this.setState({ error: '123' });
  };

  onHideRender = () => {
    this.setState({ error: '' });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.onRender}>Render Alert</button>
        <button onClick={this.onHideRender}>Hide Alert</button>
        <Alert text={this.state.error} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```